# In MYSQL create function for changing multiple characters

Tags: mysql, replace, character

I want to change some Turkish characters to English for multiple columns' rows.

Lower case characters:

ç to c, ğ to g, ı to i, ö to o, ş to s, ü to u

Upper case characters:

Ç to C, Ğ to G, İ to I, Ö to O, Ş to S, Ü to U

For example:

A column which is include 'ARÇELİK' string value.
The function which will be created should change this value to 'ARCELIK'

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to solve this issue.

My function is this.

CREATE FUNCTION `REPLACECHARS`(t1 varchar(100) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    declare s1 varchar(100) CHARSET latin1;

```
set 
s1 = REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(t1,'ç','c'),'ğ','g'),'ı','i'),'ö','o'),'ş','s'),'ü','u'),'Ç','C'),'Ğ','G'),'İ','I'),'Ö','O'),'Ş','S'),'Ü','U');
```

RETURN s1;
END

Comment: Not ideal solution but certainly time-being problem solver. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/).Think it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REPLACE` function for this.

`SELECT REPLACE('ARÇELİK','Ç','C');`

Now the Output would be `ARCELİK`.

Maybe you could put all the characters you want to replace in a table and then loop all of them through the REPLACE. I can't test this atm, it's just an idea i had in mind ;-)